# How to Fill cell background color depending a specific value from another sheet cell value in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How to Fill cell background color depending a specific value from another sheet cell value in excel?

I want fill up sheet2 cell depending on Sheet1 cell value.

Sheet 1

[image]

Sheet 2

[image]

For example, in sheet1 value 4 missing so, no need to fill up sheet2 cell that contain value 04 like that.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try:

```
Sub test()

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, cell As Range, rngFound As Range
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws1 = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws2 = .Worksheets("Sheet2")
    End With

    With ws1
        Set rng1 = .Range("A1:R1")
    End With

    With ws2

        Set rng2 = .Range("A1:E5")

        For Each cell In rng2

            Set rngFound = rng1.Find(cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)

            If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then

                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = rngFound.Interior.ColorIndex

            End If

        Next cell

    End With

End Sub
```